# Expressions not displaying some math text in R / Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, plotmath

Multiplication and division plotmath show up as empty boxes in the Rstudio IDE:

```
plot(1,2,main=expression('1'%*%10^-03))
```

[image]

Yet, if this is printed to a pdf, it is fine:

```
pdf("Figure.pdf",width=12,height=9)
plot(1,2,main=expression('1'%*%10^-03))
dev.off()
```

[image]
Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: It’s a font problem. The default font for the interactive device doesn’t have the right glyph.

Comment: Have you tried either `%cdot%` or just `x`?

Comment: `%cdot%` comes out as `%cdot%(1, 10^-3)`, which isn't what I am assuming it should be doing, and `plot(1,2,main=expression('1 x '*10^-03))` is fine as a work around, but not a general solution since it would be great to have `%/%` work as well, for example.

Comment: Maybe I got the function name wrong. Check the plotmath help page. Sure enough. It’s `%.%` . In my defense its name is “cdot”. Also consider adding spaces to separate plotmath tokens.